# R: how to add rows based on the conditions of a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
n = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7) 
s = c("aa", "aa", "bb", "dd", "dd", "ee", "ee", "gg")
b = c("Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Dec", "Mar", "Apr", "Jan", "Aug")
df = data.frame(n, s, b)

view(df)
      n  s   b
    1 1 aa Feb
    2 1 aa Jan
    3 2 bb Mar
    4 4 dd Dec
    5 4 dd Mar
    6 5 ee Apr
    7 5 ee Jan
    8 7 gg Aug
```

And I have a reference table as a .csv that I can pull into R and I used read.csv. It looks like this:

```
 view(csv)
  a  s
1 1 aa
2 2 bb
3 3 cc
4 4 dd
5 5 ee
6 6 ff
7 7 gg
```

I want to use the csv as a reference table to add whatever is missing, such as 3 cc and 7 gg back into the df. I want to insert rows that contains original values that are missing and add a row called "Not Applicable" below it. The end result should look like:

```
  n  s  b
1 1 aa Feb
2 1 aa Jan
3 2 bb Mar
4 3 cc
5 3 Not Applicable
6 4 dd Dec
7 4 dd Mar
8 5 ee Apr
9 5 ee Jan
10 6 ff
11 6 Not Applicable
12 7 gg Aug
```

Does anyone know how to do this without manually adding values to the original data frame? I want it to be able to automatically recognize the missing ones and add them itself because my real data is a lot more huge than this one. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? `merge` seems like a good candidate, as do `dplyr::left_join` and `dplyr::anti_join` (together, not individually).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks!! I haven't tried anything because I didn't know where to start. Sorry I am new to R. But I will look into dplyr :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be using `dplyr` as:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(csv, select(df, -b), by=c("n", "s")) %>%
  bind_rows(., mutate(., s = NA)) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(n)



# n    s    b
# 1  1   aa  Feb
# 2  1   aa  Jan
# 3  2   bb  Mar
# 4  3   cc <NA>
# 5  3 <NA> <NA>
# 6  4   dd  Dec
# 7  4   dd  Mar
# 8  5   ee  Apr
# 9  5   ee  Jan
# 10 6   ff <NA>
# 11 6 <NA> <NA>
# 12 7   gg  Aug
#
```

## Data

```
n = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7) 
s = c("aa", "aa", "bb", "dd", "dd", "ee", "ee", "gg")
b = c("Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Dec", "Mar", "Apr", "Jan", "Aug") 
df = data.frame(n, s, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

csv <- read.table(text = "n  s
1 1 aa
2 2 bb
3 3 cc
4 4 dd
5 5 ee
6 6 ff
7 7 gg", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, @MKR  Thank you for your answer!  I am just wondering in the code:   anti_join(csv, df, by=c("n", "s")) Do you mean that matching column n and s in both csv and df ?

Comment: @Connie Are you getting any error with that command? May be you have not used `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating `data.frame`. Have a look at data in my answer.

Comment: I do. I get an error like "Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = NA) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0" Maybe I should change the .csv before I pull it in

Comment: @Connie Please add your new `csv` so that I can try to understand the problem. You can update it as part of your question.